# Extracting table data from unevenly spaced text file

Tags: ubuntu, text-processing, awk, sed

```
         CLASS RECORD OF THE STUDENT FROM THE PREVIOUS BATCH WHO TOPPED
Name (Roll no) #    Location   Section     Rank (MARKS)     Gender   
Anna (+)            USA        A1          First (100)      Female
(04)                California V
ADDITIONAL RECORDS OF THE STUDENTS FROM THE PREVIOUS BATCH NEXT IN LIST
Name (Roll no) #    Location   Section     Rank (MARKS)     Gender
Bob (-)             USA        A2          First (99)       Male
(07)                Florida    VI
Eva (+)             USA        A4          Second (96)      Female
(12)                Ohio       V           English (99)
                                           Maths(100)
Other records are not available currently.Some records may be present which can be given on request.
```

Getting the text file from a PDF using **pdftotext**. Using below **AWK** command I am getting the above data.

Table data is unevenly space separated. Remove the lines which is the **whole line** is in **Uppercase**

```
pdftotext -layout INPUTFILE.pdf INPUTFILE.txt
awk '/RESULTS/{flag=1;next}/OTHER DATA/{flag=0}flag' INPUTFILE.txt | column -ts $'\t' -n
```

---

How do I get the table data in tab delimited format(*Below Format*)?

Code in a generic way, so it works other types of tables also.

```
Name (Roll no) #    Location    Section     Rank (MARKS)    Gender  
Anna (+)            USA         A1          First (100)     Female
(04)                California  V
Bob (-)             USA         A2          First (99)      Male
(07)                Florida     VI
Eva (+)             USA         A4          Second (96)     Female
(12)                Ohio        V           English (99)
                                            Maths (100)
```

Comment: Your desired format is not a tab-delimited table, between "(04)" and "California" I bet there are more tabs than between the first two header strings. Plus, you're already using 'column -t', so I don't understand what's being asked exactly.

Comment: There is only spaces in the whole table no TABS at all even between "(04)" and "California",. 'column -t' is not properly formatting the table.
I want to make this table content in TAB DELIMITED format.

Comment: Is the 1st column the entire string "Name (Roll no) #" and the 4th "Rank (MARKS)"? Also, in "Maths(100)" there is no space in between, but after column -t there is one now?? Did you add it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this is what you're looking for

```
$ awk '{if ($1 in a) next; a[$1]=$0; print}' <filePath> | grep -v  -e STUDENT  -e Other | column -ts $'\t' 
Name (Roll no) #    Location   Section     Rank (MARKS)     Gender   
Anna (+)            USA        A1          First (100)      Female
(04)                California V
Bob (-)             USA        A2          First (99)       Male
(07)                Florida    VI
Eva (+)             USA        A4          Second (96)      Female
(12)                Ohio       V           English (99)
                                           Maths(100)
```